# Make sub columns (a group of columns with same header) in pdfmake

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfmake

I would print a table which has a group of columns with the same cell as header. 
An example in below:

[image]

I searched possible solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454842/nested-sub-tables-with-pdfmake) but it is a nested table, different of course from my purpose.

Answer (score 9):

Use `rowSpan` for cells extending `n` rows down, and `colSpan` extending `n` columns to the right.

Try this:

```
var dd = {
    content: [
        {
            table: {
                headerRows: 2,
                body: [
                    [{text: 'Item', rowSpan: 2}, {text: 'Properties', colSpan: 3}, '', '', {text: 'Status', rowSpan: 2}],
                    ['', {text: 'A'}, {text: 'B'}, {text: 'C'}, ''],
                    ['Thing', 'Prop A', 'Prop B', 'Prop C', 'Free'],
                ]
            }
        },
    ],
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Put your required logic accordingly in the loop of the table body. Also while doing body.push() you can concatinate the props with column name (ex: props[i] +' ' + columnA[i];)

```
var columnA = "A";
var columnB = "B";
var columnC = "C";
var items = ["item1","item2","item3"];
var props = ["Prop1","Prop2","Prop3"];
var statuses = ["Free","Paid","Free"];
var dd = {
  content: [
      {
          table: {
              headerRows: 2,
              body: tableBody()
          }
      },
  ],
  styles: {
      header: {
        fontSize: 18,
        bold: true,
        color: 'red',
        alignment: 'center'
      }
  }
};  

function tableBody(){
  var arr=[];
  var body =[
              [{text: 'Item', rowSpan: 2 , style:"header"}, {text: 'Properties', 
               colSpan: 3, style:"header"}, '', '', {text: 'Status', rowSpan: 2 , 
               style:"header"}],
              ['', {text: 'A',style:"header"}, {text: 'B',style:"header"}, {text: 
                 'C',style:"header"}, '']
            ]

    for(var j = 0;j < props.length; j++){
                body.push([items[j], (props[j] + ' '+ columnA), (props[j] + ' '+ columnB), (props[j] + ' '+ columnC), statuses[j]]);

    }    
    return body;
}
```