# Make merge columns in pdfmake

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfmake

I will print a table that has a group of columns with the same cell as the header. Example below:

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXI1g.png)

I looked for a possible solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60036579/make-sub-columns-a-group-of-columns-with-same-header-in-pdfmake) but this is a table with a group of columns with the same cells as the header, of course different from the table I want.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.